# Are there benefits to ActionController::API unless our Rails app is exclusively an API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api, rack-middleware

I'm not 100% if my Rails app will always just be an API.

With that in mind, I have keep ActionController:

`class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base`

and opted to create an api controller,

`class ApiController < ActionController::API`.

Now, I have not changed my `application.rb`, so I do have any configuration pertaining to `config.api_only`.

That being said, I do know that if I to solely build an API, it could be 40% faster through `rails-api` because it cuts down on the middleware in the stack. Do I still hold this benefit by just inheriting from `ActionController::API`? If I don't have this 40% boost, are there any benefits to doing this then?