# ActionController::API vs ActionController::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, rails-api, actioncontroller

I want to know what all functionalities are restricted in API and will there be any difference in speed if we use Base in place of API.

I searched many places to find the difference between those two modules, all I was able to know it API is light weight version of Base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best source to understand the differences between both is certainly the list of modules they include in the source code.

Which [`ActionController::Base`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb#L206) includes these modules (comments removed and sorted alphabetically):

```
MODULES = [
  AbstractController::AssetPaths,
  AbstractController::Callbacks,
  AbstractController::Rendering,
  AbstractController::Translation,
  ActionView::Layouts,
  Caching,
  ConditionalGet,
  ContentSecurityPolicy,
  Cookies,
  DataStreaming,
  DefaultHeaders,
  EtagWithFlash,
  EtagWithTemplateDigest,
  Flash,
  FormBuilder,
  Helpers,
  HttpAuthentication::Basic::ControllerMethods,
  HttpAuthentication::Digest::ControllerMethods,
  HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods,
  ImplicitRender,
  Instrumentation,
  Logging,
  MimeResponds,
  ParameterEncoding,
  ParamsWrapper,
  PermissionsPolicy,
  Redirecting,
  Renderers::All,
  Rendering,
  RequestForgeryProtection,
  Rescue,
  Streaming,
  StrongParameters,
  UrlFor,
]
```

While [`ActionController::API`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/api.rb#L112) only includes these (again, comments removed and sorted alphabetically):

```
MODULES = [
  AbstractController::Callbacks,
  AbstractController::Rendering,
  ApiRendering,
  BasicImplicitRender,
  ConditionalGet,
  DataStreaming,
  DefaultHeaders,
  Instrumentation,
  Logging,
  ParamsWrapper,
  Redirecting,
  Renderers::All,
  Rescue,
  StrongParameters,
  UrlFor,
]
```

Comment: It is very insightful, can I know the possible speed difference ,     

     [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393732/are-there-benefits-to-actioncontrollerapi-unless-our-rails-app-is-exclusively )      

can you address this question too please

Comment: Only inheriting from the API instead of the Base will certainly have a performance and memory advantage. But the advantage will not be as big as if you ran the whole Rails application in API mode. Simply for the reason that an API controller loads and runs fewer modules. But when not in API mode, the application still loads all features (and not the limit API mode feature set) and therefore the application will still load modules and add middlewares that would not be loaded in API mode.